# Accessing Instagram user data without Instagram Graph API user authentication

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Is there any way to query for a public Instagram account's information without having to authenticate them via the Authorization Window?

Say I'd like to programmatically obtain any public account's number of follows, number of posts, and number of likes and comments on each post. Could I do this via Instagram's Graph API? Or would the only way be developing some kind of web scraper?